# link slowly changing dimension with fact table using another table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have one slowly changing dimension type 2, one fact table and another lookup table that links the two. isCurrent field in the dimension will be updated based on loadDate. I am trying to create a logic to load the second column of the table that links the fact and dimension but not having any luck yet. Here is what I am trying to achieve. The linking table is supposed to hold all IDs in column 1 and the corresponding LinkedID in column 2. And if the isCurrent flag changes, LinkedID column should update to the ID with isCurrent = Y. btw: ID is not employeeId, it is just a reference number that ties the dimension with the fact.

Here is an example of what the Link table should look like:

**Record 1:**
**Dimension Table**

```
ID      Name    State   isCurrent   
101     Alex    TX      Y
```

**Link table:**

```
ID      LinkedID 
101     101
```

**Record 2:**
**Dimension table:**

```
ID      Name    State   isCurrent   
101     Alex    TX      N
102     Alex    CA      Y
```

**Link table**

```
ID      LinkedID 
101     102
102     102
```

Comment: So if you insert another record for Alex,ID=103, then Link table will have 3 entries and all LinkedId will be 103?

Comment: That is correct, since the one with ID 103 will be the current one.

Comment: And how is your dimension table updated? Have you considered using trigger to achieve your requirement?

Comment: The flag fields in the dimension are updated using a procedure. That process works fine. And also I'm trying to write a script to refresh the Link table. Have not considered a trigger though.

Comment: I would suggest you to use same procedure, which is updating dimension table, to update link table as well. Alternatively you can use `after insert` trigger on the dimension table.

Comment: Will try that now, many thanks!!